# how to mark rows as Header

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing a macro in order to be able to copy data from different worksheets of my excel workbook into a word template. The basics work as intended but I have some formating issues once it is in the word file.

I tied to use the `Rows.HeadingFormat` property according to the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.rows.headingformat
but it does not work for me, as in nothing happens. There is no error Code displayed and the code after my line still compiles and on the second page of the table there is no header visible, but the `Selection.Rows.HeadingFormat` check evaluates to True. It might very well be an issue with the indexing of the tables. But as far as I understand every new table inserted gets the next index available. And as there are no tables in the template to start with the indexing should start at 1. Unless the Table of Content counts as a table but as far as I understand it has a different type than table.

My first and second row of each worksheet should end up being the header rows of each table.

Please see my code below

```vb
Sub mytry()
    Dim tblRange As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    Dim str As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Integer, lCol As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate

    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="filename", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Produces a String of Placeholders for the Word template as I don't know in advance how many worksheets there are
        str = str & "<<" & Ws.Name & "_Heading>>" & vbLf & "<<" & Ws.Name & "_Content>>"
    Next
    
    With WordDoc
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Data>>" ' Placeholder in the Word Template where all of my Data goes.
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = str
    End With
    
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' finds last used Cell in the Worksheet
        lRow = Ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        lCol = Ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
        str = SpaltNoZuBuchst(lCol) & CStr(lRow)
        Debug.Print str

        Set tblRange = Ws.Range("A1:" & str)
        tblRange.Copy

        With WordDoc
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="<<" & Ws.Name & "_Heading>>", MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True
            .Application.Selection = Ws.Name
            .Application.Selection.Style = WordDoc.Styles("Heading 1")
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" _ ", MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True, ReplaceWith:=" / "
            .Application.Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="<<" & Ws.Name & "_Content>>", MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True
            .Application.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
        End With
        i = i + 1 ' should index the newly inserted Table
        Set WordTable = WordDoc.Tables(i) ' The issue must be around here
        WordTable.Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
        WordTable.Rows(2).HeadingFormat = True ' first and second row contain Heading Information
        WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
        WordDoc.Application.Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
        WordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertBreak
    Next
    
    For j = 1 To i
        WordDoc.Tables(j).Rows(1).Select
        If Selection.Rows.HeadingFormat = True Then MsgBox "Table " & CStr(j) & " has a Heading"
    Next j

    WordDoc.TablesOfContents(1).Update
    WordDoc.Fields.Update
End Sub

Function SpaltNoZuBuchst(Num As Integer) As String
    Dim eins As Integer, zwei As Integer
    Dim str As String
    
    eins = Int((Num - 1) / 26)
    If eins - 1 > 0 Then zwei = Int((eins - 1) / 26)
    
    If zwei > 0 Then str = Chr(zwei + 64)
    If eins - zwei * 26 > 0 Then str = str + Chr(eins - zwei * 26 + 64)
    str = str + Chr(Num - eins * 26 + 64)
    
    SpaltNoZuBuchst = str
End Function
```

Comment: Is `SpaltNoZuBuchst` a function? If yes, like it looks to be,  please edit your question and post its code, too.

Comment: Does return the literal part of the last column address? If yes, you can obtain the last cell with a single code line...

Comment: "it does not work for me" is not a helpful description of your problem. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68468221/edit) link below the question and describe exactly what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: @FaneDuru I am sorry that I forgot. It just returnes the corresponding letter to the number provided.. so 1 -> A, 3-> C, 27 -> AA and so on.. yes there might be a shorter version with .End or something but I read that sometimes this can also return more cells than actually filled..

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I'm sorry I forgot as I really can't see any differnce when running the code with or without these two lines..

Comment: Not your problem, but try `str = ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address(0, 0)`. You can directly `Set` the last cell.

Comment: Applying `HeadingFormat` does exactly as described in the documentation - "Rows formatted as table headings are repeated when a table spans more than one page." So if your table doesn't span more than one page there will be no visible result.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Sorry that i forgot to mention that as well but my tables are all longer than one page and there is no header visible on the second page..

Comment: Have you checked the properties for the first two rows in the table? Is "Repeat as header row" checked?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I added a few lines to my code to check if `Selection.Rows.HeadingFormat` evaluates to True. Is that what you meant? In this case yes I got a Message box for every table stating that it has a heading but no I still cannot see it on the new page..

Comment: @TimothyRylatt or did you mean rightclicking on the table and checking the table properties? because there it is not checked..

Comment: Did you have the cursor in the first row of the table when you right-clicked? Is the document in Print Layout view?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Yes and yes

Comment: Is it possible to post the document, or the template, so that I can check it?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt The issue is that it is work related so I don't think they would be happy if I start sending around their Data.. but I just tired to use a blank document instead of the template and it did not help anything.. do you think there might be an incompatibility with the blank document as well?

Comment: Your code appears to be working correctly, but the document that is being produced isn't. Have you tried running the code on a different pc to exclude the possibility that the issue is related to your environment?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I figured out why I was not getting any Error messages.. There is a `On Error Resume Next` statement in my code and I thought it only effects the row imediately afterwards but apparently it affects the whole script.. I need to do some more testing.. I will get back to you once I have figured out more specific questions..

Comment: @TimothyRylatt it does what it should.. there is only a problem if I have merged cells in the first row. In this case it crashes with runtime error 5991 as it is unable to select a single row.. i would like to select both rows in this case.. and it is the only reason why i am selecting row 1 and row 2 in my code.. ----- as I am new to the site.. should I edit my original post or post a new question?

Comment: Post a new one.